# Postgres dblink: Getting "[2F003] ERROR: password is required Detail: Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string."

Tags: postgresql, dblink

When I try to run the following query, I get the following error message, and so my dblink queries are failing. All the hosts, roles, network connections and usernames have been set up correctly, yet it is not working.

```
select abc from dblink(
'port=5439 host=some_dbhost.mycompany.com dbname=my_db username=my_user password=<...>',
    'select 1 as x') as t1 (abc int);
```

> [2F003] ERROR: password is required Detail: Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.

No, there IS a password. What's going on?

Comment: What version are you using?  I get the better message `ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  invalid connection option "username"`

Comment: I can reproduce this now., I initially failed as I tested it as a superuser.  I'll try to write up a bug report on it.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is TOTALLY misleading.

The REAL error is that the username was incorrectly specified as `username`.

The correct form specified as `user`  (while the db is specified as `dbname`, so annoying!)

The fix is:

```
select abc from dblink(
'port=5439 host=some_dbhost.mycompany.com dbname=my_db user=my_user password=<...>',
    'select 1 as x') as t1 (abc int);
```

So the error probably should have read as one of:

- `argument user missing`
- `unknown argument username specified`

instead of this *stay up until 3am screaming to the heavens* thing.

Comment: Screaming is not a solution - report the problem to the pgsql-hackers mailing list.

Comment: I have faced lot of different issues while all they are giving the same error message you mention.